# SOAP service returns empty array via WSDL instead of data from database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to write my own SOAP server and to call methods via SoapClient(wsdl mode). I created methods in php, added an auto-generated wsdl file. I send request via SoapClient and server should work with Mysql and return results, but i am always getting empty response. I checked logs in MySQL and they show correct request that should return the data.

```
public function getCarMakes()
{
    $carMakesArr = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars order by make";
    try
    {
        foreach($this->conn->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            $carMakesArr[] = array( $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

        return $carMakesArr;
}
```

My WSDL file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is Metro/2.3.1-b419 (branches/2.3.1.x-7937; 2014-08-04T08:11:03+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.10-b140803.1500 JAXWS-API/2.2.11 JAXB-RI/2.2.10-b140802.1033 JAXB-API/2.2.12-b140109.1041 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://wsdl.example.org/" name="ServerWS" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:tns="http://wsdl.example.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://wsdl.example.org/" schemaLocation="ServerWS_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="buyCar">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:buyCar"/>
  </message>
  <message name="buyCarResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:buyCarResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarMakes">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarMakes"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarMakesResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarDetailsById">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarDetailsById"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getCarDetailsByIdResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarDetailsByIdResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="searchByParams">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByParams"/>
  </message>
  <message name="searchByParamsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:searchByParamsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="ServerWS">
    <operation name="buyCar">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/buyCarRequest" message="tns:buyCar"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/buyCarResponse" message="tns:buyCarResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarMakes">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarMakesRequest" message="tns:getCarMakes"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarMakesResponse" message="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarDetailsById">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarDetailsByIdRequest" message="tns:getCarDetailsById"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/getCarDetailsByIdResponse" message="tns:getCarDetailsByIdResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="searchByParams">
      <input wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/searchByParamsRequest" message="tns:searchByParams"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://wsdl.example.org/ServerWS/searchByParamsResponse" message="tns:searchByParamsResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="ServerWSPortBinding" type="tns:ServerWS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="buyCar">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarMakes">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getCarDetailsById">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="searchByParams">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="ServerWS">
    <port name="ServerWSPort" binding="tns:ServerWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost/soap/server.php"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

My XML schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="getCarMakes">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id_array1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getCarMakesResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

My request via SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/soap/ServerWS.wsdl',
                        array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
                              'trace' => 1,
                              'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2)
                             );

try
    {

        $arr = (array)$client->getCarMakes();

        echo "<b>First method:</b> <br>";

    }
    catch(SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $client->__getLastRequest();
    echo $client->__getLastResponse(); 
     var_dump($arr);
```

It returns an empty array, however db is there and data is there. Request to db is correct, i initially created server in non-wsdl mode and it worked just fine.

My request:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<env:envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl.example.org/">
<env:body><ns1:getcarmakes></ns1:getcarmakes>
   </env:body></env:envelope>
```

The response, i get:

```
  <env:envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl.example.org/">
    <env:body><ns1:getcarmakesresponse></ns1:getcarmakesresponse>
    </env:body>
  </env:envelope>
```

Please advise.

Comment: What happens if you try both sides independantly ? First the getCarMakes() function to see the results it should return, and then the WSDL linked to a unit-test getCarMakes() function returning non-empty fixed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with auto-generated WSDL:

- I found the working WSDL.
- Updated it with my complex types and voila, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There was at least no proper definition of complex types. Below is basic implementation which returns a list of available car makes (as array of strings). If return format should be different, definition of `carMakesArray` complex type should be adjusted accordingly.

Put the following files on the same level and replace `your.host` in all of them with the actual base URL at which these files will be accessible.

*ServerWS.wsdl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://your.host/"
             name="ServerWS"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:tns="http://your.host/"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
>
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://your.host/">
            <complexType name="carMakesArray">
                <complexContent>
                    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
                    </restriction>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="getCarMakesResponse">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="return" type="tns:carMakesArray"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>        
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="getCarMakes" />
    <message name="getCarMakesResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="ServerWS">
        <operation name="getCarMakes">
            <input wsam:Action="http://your.host/ServerWS/getCarMakesRequest" message="tns:getCarMakes"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://your.host/ServerWS/getCarMakesResponse" message="tns:getCarMakesResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="ServerWSPortBinding" type="tns:ServerWS">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="getCarMakes">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="ServerWS">
        <port name="ServerWSPort" binding="tns:ServerWSPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://your.host/soapServerTest.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

*soapServerTest.php*

```
<?php
require 'CarService.php';

$soapServer = new \SoapServer('http://your.host/ServerWS.wsdl', ['cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE]);
$soapServer->setClass('CarsService');
$soapServer->handle();
```

*CarService.php*

```
<?php
class CarsService
{
    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getCarMakes()
    {
        /** Here you may extract data from DB and return instead of hard-coded values */
        return ['BMW', 'Ford', 'Honda'];
    }
}
```

*soapClientTest.php*

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://your.host/ServerWS.wsdl',
    array(
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    )
);
try {
    $makes = $client->getCarMakes();
    var_dump($makes);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```